# Debugging Perl one-liner for renaming files

Tags: perl

I was testing/trying out [this Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111868/what-is-your-latest-useful-perl-one-liner-or-a-pipe-involving-perl), and I'm trying to figure out what happened to the files. I don't see the files anymore.
Did I delete them or what went wrong?

Example of file names listed (original):

```
IMG_0178.JPG
IMG_0182.JPG
IMG_0183.JPG
IMG_0184.JPG
IMG_0186.JPG
```

I wanted to simply change the file extension to lowercase (.jpg):

```
perl -e'while(<*.JPG>) { s/JPG$/jpg/; rename <*.jpg>, $_ }'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `rename` with a glob. Use scalars. Try to assign the file name to a new variable before the substitution and rename the old name to the modified one, like this:

```
perl -e'while(<*.JPG>) { ($new = $_) =~ s/JPG$/jpg/; rename $_, $new }'
```

Check output with `ls -1`:

```
IMG_0178.jpg                                                                                                     
IMG_0182.jpg                                                                                                
IMG_0183.jpg                                                                                              
IMG_0184.jpg                                                                                               
IMG_0186.jpg
```

Comment: thanks. so the glob that I was using was `rename <*.jpg>`? In my example, were the files deleted? Thanks again

Comment: @cjd143SD: Your command didn't delete anything in my test. It left files with same name, but I guess that `<*.jpg>` doesn't match anything. I tried with `<*.JPG>` instead and worked, but as I told you before, I prefer to use `rename` with scalars.

Answer (score 4):

Bizarrely your code should do what you wanted.

A file glob like `<*.JPG>` in scalar context will return the next file that matches the pattern, and since both `while` and `rename` apply scalar context, the two globs return the same value at each iteration.

```
while (<*.JPG>) {
    s/JPG$/jpg/;
    rename <*.jpg>, $_;
}
```

In the first iteration of the loop `$_` is set to `IMG_0178.JPG` by the `while`, and the substitution sets the file type to lower case.

Then in the rename `<*.jpg>` is executed in scalar context and again returns `IMG_0178.JPG` - the first file in the same list because Windows file names are case-insensitive.

So finally the rename performs `rename 'IMG_0178.JPG', 'IMG_0178.jpg'` as required.

Rewriting `rename` like this shows this clearly

```
sub ren($$) {
  print "$_[0] -> $_[1]\n";
}

while (my $file = <*.JPG>) {
  $file =~ s/JPG$/jpg/;
  ren <*.JPG>, $file;
}
```

**output**

```
IMG_0178.JPG -> IMG_0178.jpg
IMG_0182.JPG -> IMG_0182.jpg
IMG_0183.JPG -> IMG_0183.jpg
IMG_0184.JPG -> IMG_0184.jpg
IMG_0186.JPG -> IMG_0186.jpg
```

So you are lucky, and your files should have been renamed as you wanted.

But *don't* do this. In particular you should run the program with a print statement in place of any critical operations so that you can see what is going to happen.

This would be better as id more clearly does what is intended

```
perl -e '($f = $_) =~ s/JPG$/jpg/i and rename $_, $f while <*.JPG>'
```