# perl command line one liner to do find/replace, but *not* print lines that don't match?

Tags: regex, perl, command-line, one-liner

I want to do a regex find & replace on a file on the command line with complicated regex, so I need PCRE's & am using `perl -pe "s/foo/bar"` (rather than `sed`), that prints out all lines after applying the `s///`, but it also prints lines that don't match.

Is there a `perl` command line one-liner which will not print lines that don't match? I know of `perl -pe s/foo/bar/ if /foo/`, but then I need to duplicate the regex. Is it possible without repeating myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`-n` flag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-n*) (which, unlike `-p`, does not automatically print all lines) and print only lines which match the regex:

```
perl -ne 's/foo/bar/ && print'
```

Or, equivalently:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/foo/bar/'
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Dada shows the most concise method to solve the OP's exact problem.
Below are a few other equivalent, but longer, methods to do the same. Their advantage is that these one-liners can be more easily expanded to execute some other additional code (if needed) in addition to simply printing the lines.

```
perl -ne 'if ( s{foo}{bar} ) { print; }'
# Same:
perl -ne 'next LINE unless s{foo}{bar}; print;'
```

These can be expanded to:

```
perl -ne 'if ( s{foo}{bar} ) { some(); other(); code(); print; }'
# Same:
perl -ne 'next LINE unless s{foo}{bar}; some(); other(); code(); print;'
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[perlrun: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[What should every Perl hacker know about perl -ne?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2212378/967621)

To see these command line switches in a variety of use cases, including some great Perl one-liners, see:
[What is your latest useful Perl one-liner (or a pipe involving Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111868/967621)